# Cannot access MYSQL using inline password

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-envoy

I cant connect to mysql if I do this:

```
mysql -ualan -psecret
```

It returns:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'alan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But if I do:

```
mysql -ualan -p
```

And then I enter the password it works.

I NEED to use the inline password since I'm writing a script to synchronize databases with Laravel/Envoy and it doesnt allow prompt inputs.

Am I missing some configuration or something?

Comment: Assuming your password is not `secret`, are any special characters properly escaped?

Comment: What kind of characters should be escaped? and how can I escape them?

Comment: Those with special meaning in your shell.

Comment: I changed the password to something cleaner and it works. Post and answer so I can vote it!

Comment: Just put the password in quotes. This is not special to MySQL, it's how you use the Unix shell in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your password has special characters in your shell, you would need to quote or escape them.

In bash or bash-like shells, this should work:

```
mysql -ualan -p'te$t'
```

Or

```
mysql -ualan -pte\$t
```